The JavaScript Markdown syntax converter code transforms the sublist into a list in Markdown at VSCode's Markdown preview
I write in pure Markdown at VSCode and always use the VSCode Markdown Preview. I created a new Markdown syntax code called infoboxcard that is not supported officially by markdown-it and by CommonMark.
As I do not like to create a markdown-it plugin because VSCode Markdown can't read if it is not an extension. I decided to write in vanilla JavaScript.
I create the list and the sublist for the genealogical ascendancy or descendancy. I create an ancestral profile card for each item.
Here is the small code in Markdown:
- 
    ```infoboxcard
    ![Cláudio Costa](https://xsgames.co/randomusers/avatar.php?g=male){avatar}
    Cláudio Muniz Costa
    24 October 1980 in  São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil
    10 December 2060 in Rio de Janeiro, Rio de Janeiro, Brazil
    **Nationality:** :br:
    **Citizenship:** :br:
    **Ancestries:** :es: :pt:
    ```
  - 
    ```infoboxcard
    ![Fabiana Alves Costa](https://xsgames.co/randomusers/avatar.php?g=female){avatar}
    Fabiana Conti Alves Costa
    11 September 1985 in São José dos Campos, São Paulo, Brazil
    15 March 2082 in Niterói, Rio de Janeiro, Brazil
    **Nationality:** :br:
    **Citizenship:** :br: :it:
    **Ancestries:** :it: :pt:
    ```
    - Child 1
    - Child 2
    - Child 3

I wrote in pure JavaScript, using the regular expressions to replace two tags – <pre> and <code class="language-infoboxcard">, rendered by VSCode's Markdown, with <div class="infoboxcard">, and other regular expressions to replace Markdown syntax codes because it was transformed into <pre><code>, thereby prevents VSCode's Markdown Preview from rendering the remaining code. Follow the JavaScript:
window.onload = () =>
{
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
    /<pre><code(?:\s+[^>]*)?class="[^"]*language-infoboxcard[^"]*"[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/code><\/pre>/g,
    (_, match) =>
    {
      let innerContent = match
        .trim()
        .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
        .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
        .replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
        .replace(/&#39;/g, "'")
        .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
        .replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '</p><p>')  // Convert each line to a paragraph
        .replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, '<b>$1</b>')
        .replace(/__(.*?)__/g, '<i>$1</i>')
        .replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, '<i>$1</i>')
        .replace(/_(.*?)_/g, '<i>$1</i>')
        .replace(/\*\*_(.*?)_\*\*/g, '<b><i>$1</i></b>')
        .replace(/_\*\*(.*?)\*\*_/, '<i><b>$1</b></i>')
        .replace(/\:br\:/g, '')
        .replace(/\:es\:/g, '')
        .replace(/\:pt\:/g, '')
        .replace(/\:it\:/g, '')
        .replace(/!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)\{(.*?)\}/g, '<img src="$2" alt="$1" class="$3">')
        .replace(/!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/g, '<img src="$2" alt="$1">')
        .replace(/!\[(.*?)\]\{(.*?)\}/g, '<img class="$2" alt="$1">');

      return `<div class="infoboxcard">${innerContent}</div>`;
    }
  );

  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
    /(<div class="infoboxcard">[^"]*<img src="[^"]*"[^>]*><p><\/p>)/g,
    '$1<div>'
  ).replace(
    /<\/p><\/div>/g,
    '</p></div></div>'
  );

  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
    /(<div class="male"><\/div>)/g,
    '$1<div>'
  ).replace(
    /<\/p><\/div>/g,
    '</p></div></div>'
  );
};

I noticed that the code ends up transforming this sublist into a list. Compare this small screenshot:

I wrote everything in pure HTML, and tested it. It worked. I do not know why the JavaScript code messed it. Then compare the image:

The code in HTML should look like:
<li data-line="2" class="code-line" dir="auto">
  <div class="infoboxcard">
    <img src="https://xsgames.co/randomusers/avatar.php?g=male" alt="Cláudio Costa" class="avatar">
    <div>
      <p>Cláudio Muniz Costa</p>
      <p>24 October 1980 in São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil</p>
      <p>10 December 2060 in Rio de Janeiro, Rio de Janeiro, Brazil</p>
      <p><b>Nationality:</b> </p>
      <p><b>Citizenship:</b> </p>
      <p><b>Ancestries:</b>  </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="infoboxcard">
        <img src="https://xsgames.co/randomusers/avatar.php?g=female" alt="Fabiana Alves Costa" class="avatar">
        <div>
          <p>Fabiana Conti Alves Costa</p>
          <p>11 September 1985 in São José dos Campos, São Paulo, Brazil</p>
          <p>15 March 2082 in Niterói, Rio de Janeiro, Brazil</p>
          <p><b>Nationality:</b> </p>
          <p><b>Citizenship:</b>  </p>
          <p><b>Ancestries:</b>  </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>Child 1</li>
        <li>Child 2</li>
        <li>Child 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

If you need the CSS code, feel free to use it:
.infoboxcard {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 64px auto;
    gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
}

.infoboxcard img {
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
}
.infoboxcard img + p
{
    display: none;
}

.infoboxcard p
{
    margin: 0;
}

.infoboxcard p:nth-child(2)
{
    color: red;
}

.infoboxcard p:nth-child(2)::before
{
    /*  birth icon */
    content: " ";
}

.infoboxcard p:nth-child(3)
{
    color: blue;
}

.infoboxcard p:nth-child(3)::before
{
    /*  death icon */
    content: " ";
}


your markdown list item have different indentation . the first one has 0 space, the second has 1space and the last ones have 3 spaces . that's enough to turn this into sublist i believe :)

I converted everything to spaces, enabled visbiles white spaces and tested it. It still has the same problem. You can see the screenshot with the white spaces: https://i.imgur.com/6zbgeGV.png.

You probably want to use a plugin like https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it-container instead of just modifying the HTML after the fact.
